# Searching for a Hex value in lined text file in Rust

Tags: rust

so I have a text file with about 20 million lines, that has all values sorted by Alphabet (All have the same size). I am searching for a specific value in the list.

Hex value like this: 1a9bc7e1458b964d6af0f65459ab7bb2f4a7d70a1f6480b8

And the list goes like:

- 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
- 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
- 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002

(The list has bigger values, not like provided)

I tried to bruteforce the search to scan the entire file if it matches or not, but that took ages (21 secs)

I loaded the file using BufReader and go line by line, when the line value was bigger then the given one, the program will exit.

I am open to any speed improvement.

Thanks

Comment: So the file is sorted? You could try a binary search with [`Seek`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Seek.html)

Comment: Please provide your existing code.

Comment: if it's not sorted. and a database is out of the question. rust is extremely good at multithreading. if you load the file into memory, and then search each line on a different thread maybe? or give slices of it to different threads. depending on your needs. this could reduce 21 seconds to around 3. It's not a solution, but an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a proof of concept for binary searching a 32 byte value in a file containing sorted 32 byte values separated by a one byte delimiter (like a newline). In the worst case, this would do `log2(number of elements)` random reads of 32 bytes. This should be much faster than reading the whole file.

```rust
use std::io::{Read, Seek};

fn main() {
    std::fs::write(
        "data.txt",
        "1dcca23355272056f04fe8bf20edfce0
26ab0db90d72e28ad0ba1e22ee510510
31d30eea8d0968d6458e0ad0027c9f80
48a24b70a0b376535542b996af517398
6d7fce9fee471194aa8b5b6e47267f03
7c5aba41f53293b712fd86d08ed5b36e
84bc3da1b3e33a18e8d5e1bdd7a18d7a
9ae0ea9e3c9c6e1b9b6252c8395efdc1
b026324c6904b2a9cb4b88d6d61c81d1
c30f7472766d25af1dc80b3ffc9a58c7",
    )
    .unwrap();

    let size = 32;

    let mut file = std::fs::File::open("data.txt").unwrap();
    let len = (file.metadata().unwrap().len() + 1) / size;

    for query in [
        "84bc3da1b3e33a18e8d5e1bdd7a18d7a",
        "26ab0db90d72e28ad0ba1e22ee510510",
        "c30f7472766d25af1dc80b3ffc9a58c7",
        "26ab0db90d72e28ad0ba1e22ee51051a",
    ] {
        let mut l = 0;
        let mut r = len - 1;
        let mut buf = [0u8; 32];
        let mut index = None;
        while l <= r {
            let m = l + (r - l) / 2;
            let offset = m * (size + 1);
            file.seek(std::io::SeekFrom::Start(offset)).unwrap();
            file.read_exact(&mut buf).unwrap();
            if buf.as_slice() < query.as_bytes() {
                l = m + 1
            } else if buf.as_slice() > query.as_bytes() {
                r = m - 1
            } else {
                index = Some(m);
                break;
            }
        }
        println!("query={:?} index={:?}", query, index);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
query="84bc3da1b3e33a18e8d5e1bdd7a18d7a" index=Some(6)
query="26ab0db90d72e28ad0ba1e22ee510510" index=Some(1)
query="c30f7472766d25af1dc80b3ffc9a58c7" index=Some(9)
query="26ab0db90d72e28ad0ba1e22ee51051a" index=None
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e8b3c91d8a0607389f0da31fbc059dd2)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to search in that file often, perhaps you'd want to store the data in some sort of a database. SQLite is one of the simplest options. The key is not to search the data sequentially, but to use an **index**.

### A database management system

Virtually all (R)DMBSs provide indexes that allow you to quickly find a value. If you use MySQL, for example, and put those values in a table with one column and make that column a primary key, then MySQL will store that data efficiently and searching for a specific value would take just a few page reads. You could do the same with other RDBMSs, it's just that in MySQL (InnoDB) every table is a B-Tree index itself, so that would save some storage, compared to most other RDBMSs.

If you want to save some more storage, you could also store the values as binaries (HEX string representation takes twice as many bytes). That might also help you improve performance even more.

MySQL, PostgreSQL and some other DBMSs also provide the option to automatically compress the data. So if storage size is a concern for you, you might sacrifice a little bit of performance to save space (but that performance cost would probably be negligible).

### A file

If you have a good reason not to use a DBMS, you could do something like a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). With 20 mln recs, that would mean ~ 25 scattered reads. With modern disks (SSD, NVMe, etc.), that would be much faster than sequentially reading the whole file.

You can use [seek()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Seek.html) and [read_exact()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_exact) to read at a given position in the file.

### Multiple files

If you have a good reason not to use a DBMS, and you don't want to complicate your logic with algorithms like binary search (not that it's all that complex, but still), and you are fine with storing the data in multiple files, you could split the data by a prefix, a hash or whatever makes sense for your case. If you have, say, 100 files with nice distribution, you could perform a simple search on just one small file.

Comment: won't a binary search only work if it's sorted? - which presumably it is.

Comment: @RobertCotterman Yes. From the question: 'all values sorted by Alphabet (All have the same size)'.

Comment: Thanks for your recomendations. I will split the file and index it by the hex range and then when I call a search, I will just look if the first index of the file is bigger or smaller then the value (Cause its sorted haha)

Comment: @LPbigFish If you go with the split-into-many-files option, it will be best if you don't need to read even partial data from files in order to find the file you need. One simple approach would be to create (up to 256) files like `data_00` , `data_01`, ...,  `data_ff` and distribute data based on the suffixes of your values, so that values ending with `00` go to file `data_00`, values ending with `01` go to file `data_01`, etc. That way, if you need to search for a given string that ends with `d7` for example, you will **know** that you only need to check the `data_d7` file.